# PHP version problem?

Tags: php, wp-admin

I'm ussing php7.0, im not sure, but i think the problem is the version, which versión should i use?, thank you so much.

By the way,  my apologies for my english [image]

Comment: you should ask the author of the theme to fix the bug, or switch to php 5.6